# VLOOKUP through dates and copying the values

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table in Prices worksheet which consists of prices and dates. I am trying to use VLOOKUP with VBA to look for prices pertaining to the month of January and then copying these prices onto another worksheet. But because the dates are in DATE format, I am stuck with the VBA code.

Eg.

Column A shows the dates
Column B shows the prices. 
There maybe prices shown on different dates e.g. 01/01/2014 or 02/01/2011 etc

I wanted to copy the prices for January.

Comment: Could you use a workaround? If so, create a filter and copy/paste the results  ;)

Comment: Where are you trying to put those values?  Into a separate sheet? Please specify the Sheet names you are using.

Comment: HI! I am putting them onto another sheet. Prices are in the Prices sheet and the output sheet are called Annual Prices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this, but it is only taking into account the prices that are for January.  It's easy enough to make it work for all the months, but I'm not sure how you would want to lay that out.  This grabs all January, no matter what the year.  If you wanted to add the year as well, you'd just nest another IF statement.  Make the first IF YEAR, and the second Month.

```
Sub MonthFromDate()

Dim tempMonth As Long
Dim tempDate As Date
Dim lastSourceRow As Long, tRow As Long
Dim source As String, target As String

source = "Prices"             'Source Sheet Name is set here
target = "Annual Prices"      'Target Sheet
tRow = Sheets(target).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row + 1
lastSourceRow = Sheets(source).Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row

For lRow = 2 To lastSourceRow        'Start looping through source sheet at Row 2 for Headers
    tempDate = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, 1)
    tempMonth = Month(tempDate)

    If tempMonth = 1 Then      'This is where you would insert a VARIABLE for 1.
        Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 1).Value = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, 1).Value
        Sheets(target).Cells(tRow, 2).Value = Sheets(source).Cells(lRow, 2).Value
        tRow = tRow + 1
    End If
Next lRow
End Sub
```

[image: Prices]
[image: Annual Prices]

Comment: Thank you! I will try and ask you again!

Comment: Hi peege, I have an error that says 

Run-time error '9' Subscript out of range

at the command that says lastsourcerow= sheets

Comment: That is usually indicative of the sheet name not being correct. Is the sheet "Prices"?

Comment: Hi I got it done already! Because when I retrieve data, there is a cell in the date column which is in text form. So when I remove that last cell, the macro runs!